# Concat env-entry in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, web.xml

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>sielae_url</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>https://www.bidiso.es/sielae/</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>

<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>Team/api_url</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>api/equipo.htm?id=EMB_HISP</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

The thing is, I want my second env-entry to be the concat of "sielae_url" with the string "api/equipo.htm?id=EMB_HISP". I have tried:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>Team/api_url</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value><env-entry>sielae_url</env-entry>api/equipo.htm?id=EMB_HISP</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible and you'll have to compute the composed value where needed. That could be done a single time in a service you'd inject where you need the composed value though

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will do it that way